# How can I run Jboss as a daemon on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, jboss, installation, virtual-machine, redhat

What I've done so far according to these [instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=652472) is unziped and moved jboss into my `/usr/local/` directory.  Then I put the `jboss_init_redhat.sh` script in `/etc/init.d/` as jboss and edited the script to meet my configurations.  I then run `/etc/init.d/jboss start` and all it says is

```
JBOSS_CMD_START = cd /usr/local/jboss-4.2.3.GA//bin; /usr/local/jboss-4.2.3.GA//bin/run.sh -c default -b 0.0.0.0
```

and then nothing happens.  Also if I go into `/usr/local/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin` and run `run.sh` it starts the server but when I go to the `vm's IP:8080` in my browser I still get nothing.  Any help would be appreciated also I don't know much about doing this so excuse my inexperience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init scripts should be owned and started by root.

The init script you use uses su (better would be to runuser) to change to the jboss user.

The jboss user itself does not have permission to do that.

The jboss user also does not have permission to write to /var/run etc.

So run `sudo /etc/init.d/jboss start` (you need to set up sudo first to allow this) or change to the root account and execute `/etc/init.d/jboss start`.

If it still fails check the logs at `/usr/local/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/log`.

Hope this helps.